# Can tension change in a massless string if there are three forces acting on it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Consider this massless string, which has three forces acting on it, two on the ends and one at the middle:

[image: String pulled at the left with force of 5 newtons (directed left), 5 newtons in the middle (left) and 10 newtons in the right (directed right).]

Would the tension change at the midpoint where the $5 \text{N}$ force is applied? I think it would; I think that the tension is $5 \text{N}$ on the left side and $10 \text{N}$ on the right side, and zero net force acts on the piece of string at the midpoint because there is a $5 \text{N}$ applied force and $5 \text{N}$ tension to the left and a $10 \text{N}$ tension to the right. Is this thinking correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The tension is 10 N on the right side and 5 N on the left.